# Restrict multiple checks in kendo grid

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid, with checkboxes as a column. I want to restrict multiple checks on this. i.e. User must be able to check only one row, not more than 1.

Please help me on this.

Edit:

The checkboxes are generated using clientTemplate. I have bounded the column with the grid.

```
     columns.Bound(p => p.FlightNo).HeaderTemplate(" ")
    .ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' name='chbox' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Sortable(false).Filterable(false).Width(50);
```

Thanks
Manikandan

Comment: You have to assign to all of them the same name or you should implement a function that when value is checked it verifies the values (depends on how you have generated the checkbox).

Comment: If i chose to use the same name for all checkboxes, will it restrict multiple checks?

Comment: are the checkboxes permanently visible or only when entering edit mode? How did you generate them? a template or an editor? Can you edit the original post and show some code

Comment: If you only want to have one selected, why do not use radio buttons. In your template if you just change `type='checkbox'` by `type='radio'` it would work

Comment: But i want it to be checkboxes. The column on whole has checkboxes, which is used to get the checked row. So, can you help?

Comment: I cannot see what is p `chbox` in your model. I guess that is not a field in the model, right? do you have pagination? If you have pagination and you check the checkbox and move to another page and get back, you will be loosing whatever you have checked because you are not saving it. Is this a problem? I might provide you link a to a code that does something similar but depends on your requirements you will need to change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkboxes don't use to be mutually exclusive, so you need some JavaScript code for getting what you look for.

Lets say that your grid identification is `grid`. You would need the following code for removing any other checked box.

```
$("#grid").on("change", "input.chkbxq", function (e) {
    var v = $(this).is(":checked");
    $("input.chkbxq", "#grid").prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", v);
});
```

What I do is:

1. Define a handler for any HTML `input` that has the class `chkbxq`.
2. Get the status of the checked input.
3. Set to false any input checkbox with class `chkbxq`
4. Finally set the status of the checked input to the value. This is needed since we have removed it in the previous step.

Problem: Checkbox state is not persisted when you play with pagination as you can see in a running example of this technique here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/eDu3k/2/

Comment: Can i get other column values of that checked row? If yes, how can i get that?

Comment: It is not a good practice include question in comments since you limit the exposure and reduce the changes of getting a reply.

Comment: this is proper answer. It explain step by step about the things happenning.