# How to save manually updated data in kendo grid inline edit mode

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have a column in my grid that needs to be mutually exclusive checkboxes. I used this post [Restrict multiple checks in kendo grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195880/restrict-multiple-checks-in-kendo-grid) to remove all other checked statuses and add only to the item just clicked. This is working almost exactly as I want, however, when I click the Update button for the row being edited, any boxes that were unchecked during the edit revert back to being checked. Is there a way that I can manually mark those rows as dirty? Or perhaps just save the entire grid?

Other info that may be important is that we are doing a logical batch save of the grid. The Update and Delete buttons link to empty controllers and we have a separate button that sends the viewmodel to the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.

On checkbox click, I get the uid of the element and then change each of the checkbox's values to false where the uid doesn't equal the uid of the clicked checkbox..

```
function makeCbxMutuallyExclusive(cbx) {
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var ds = grid.dataSource;
    var uid = ds.at(cbx.closest("tr").index()).uid;
    var data = ds.data();
    $.each(data, function (i, ele) {
        if (data[i].uid != uid) {
            data[i].IsPrimary = false;
        }
    });
}
```

This changes the underlying value, instead of just making a temporary cosmetic change like I was experiencing when only changing the checked properties of the checkboxes.